# SwipeToDismess - SwipeToDismiss overlays on the next list item when swiped. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using `SwipeToDismiss` in Jetpack Compose to delete items from a list. The problem is whenever you swipe an item that has something under it, it deletes the swiped item, but the swiped screen doesn't disappear.

This image shows the problem.
[image]

It is overlaying the item below it.

Here is my code for SwipeToDismiss

```
val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
    confirmStateChange = {
        if (it == DismissValue.DismissedToStart) {
            storedItemsViewModel.deleteOne(sentence)
        }
        true
    }
)
val direction = dismissState.dismissDirection
SwipeToDismiss(
    state = dismissState,
    /***  create dismiss alert Background */
    directions = setOf(
        DismissDirection.EndToStart
    ),
    dismissThresholds = { /*direction ->*/
        FractionalThreshold(if (direction == DismissDirection.EndToStart) 0.1f else 0.5f)
        FractionalThreshold(0.2f)
    },
    background = {
        val color = when (dismissState.dismissDirection) {
            DismissDirection.StartToEnd -> Color.Green
            DismissDirection.EndToStart -> Color.Red
            null -> Color.Transparent
        }
        val alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
        val icon = Icons.Default.Delete
        val scale by animateFloatAsState(
            //this scales the icon
            if (dismissState.targetValue == DismissValue.Default) 0.75f else 1f
        )
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color)
                .padding(horizontal = Dp(20f)),
            contentAlignment = alignment
        ) {
            Icon(
                icon,
                contentDescription = "Delete Icon",
                modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
            )
        }
    },

    /**** Dismiss Content */
    dismissContent = {
        Card(elevation = animateDpAsState( if (dismissState.dismissDirection != null) 4.dp else 0.dp).value) {
            FavoriteItem(sentence, word, grammar)
        }
    },
)
```

Comment: Did you find out what causes the bug? Funnily I have the same issue, 8 months later.

Comment: I am also having same issue. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Been awhile since I've done this project, but I believe what I had to do was pass a MutableList of items to the Swipe composable. Then in the dismiss state, DismissValue.DismissedToStart -> remove the item from the MutableList. 

This was all done inside of a LazyColumn.

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide unique key for lazyItems.

```
 LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()) {
                    items(
                        cartRowList,
                        key ={ cartRow -> cartRow.id},
                        itemContent = {  it ->
                            val currentItem by rememberUpdatedState(it.item)
                            val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
                                confirmStateChange = {
                                    CartDataProcessing.deleteItem(context,currentItem!!)
                                    true
                                }
```

...